# Working with newly created db for migrations in node-db-migrate (PostgreSQL)

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, migration, database-migration

I'm using node-db-migrate to test e2e database api
I'm trying to create a new db and then run the migrates on it however it doesn't seem to work on postgres.

this is my database.json

```
{
"test": {
    "driver": "pg",
    "user": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "database": "postgres",
    "port": "5432"
  }
}
```

this is the stages i did.

create a new db

```
db-migrate db:create testDB --config test/database.json -e test
```

create a new migration

```
db-migrate create migrationname -e test --config test/database.json --sql-file
```

in the sql

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;

CREATE TABLE test.Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

now i should be using the db-migrate up command such as

```
db-migrate up --config test/database.json -e test
```

however my problem is that i can't find a way to use the sql migration on the new db.

I'm actively trying to avoid setting it statically in the json because in my use case the db name is changing per execution